# python 3.6 spatialite 4.3 on mac

Tags: python, spatialite, mac

In researching this problem, it appears that there is an issue with loading extensions in sqlite3 that requires a recompile of sqlite3 so SELECT load_extension("mod_spatialite.dylib") can be called.   I have not been able to succeed recompiling sqlite3 on the mac or found anyway to access a spatialite 4.3 database using Python 3.6 or greater on the MAC. Has anyone been successful with this?